# Start 3rd Element from second column in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a basic html markup, where i am trying to use minimal html wrappers to achieve the design.
So my goal is without adding more html wrappers, using flex, force 3rd flex item to start from second column like here

```
1 2
  3
```

Of course, we can achieve adding `padding/margin-left` for the 3rd element, but I am looking for a solution with css flex and using minimal html markup.
Here is the screenshot what I am trying to achieve[image]

Basically the title and text should start from the same column.

See the code snippet and [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-dirac-3vwsnm?file=/style.css:0-676), if you want to test it more

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  column-gap: 15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo-image {
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding-top: 10px;
  order: 1;
}

.headline {
  color: white;
  order: 2;
  padding-left: 10px;

}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  order: 3;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 90%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <h4 class="headline">
          Block Title
        </h4>
         <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" width="50px" class="logo-image" alt="img" />
        <p class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente
          aliquid sit, cupiditate
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="btn">
        <button>click</button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you would use CSS Grid for this layout.

Something like this (no changes to the HTML):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: grey;
  column-gap: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr;
}

.logo-image {
  padding-top: 10px;
  order: 1;
}

.headline {
  color: white;
  order: 2;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.text {
  grid-column: 2;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  order: 3;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 90%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h4 class="headline">
      Block Title
    </h4>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" width="50px" class="logo-image" alt="img" />
    <p class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente aliquid sit, cupiditate
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
```

But if you can only use flex, then you'll have to:

1. Define a height on the container.
2. Set the `flex-direction` to `column`.
3. Set `flex-wrap` to `wrap`.
4. Give the first column (containing the image) full height, so it creates a column and forces its siblings into the second column.

(Again, no changes to the HTML.)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: grey;
  column-gap: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 200px; /* new (for demo purposes) */
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* new */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo-image {
  flex-basis: 100%;      /* new */
  object-fit: contain;   /* new (for proper image rendering) */
  object-position: top;  /* new (for proper image rendering) */
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding-top: 10px;
  order: 1;
}

.headline {
  color: white;
  order: 2;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  order: 3;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 90%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h4 class="headline">Block Title</h4>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" width="50px" class="logo-image" alt="img" />
    <p class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente
      aliquid sit, cupiditate
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
```

If you can't define a height on the container, then use the Grid version.

Comment: thanks for the answer. 
One question, please. The solution both with grid and flex works fine. Since I was trying to implement via flex, I faced a problem with image. 
As you can see, there is too much space between image and button. Even though you apply `object-fit: contain`  to image and visually it looks good, but it takes the whole height, and applying `max-width` and `max-width` breaks the style. Could you help me to fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Using flex, with an image as a flex item, and the `order` property, and the wrapping, and the `column`-direction, appears to be too much for the browser to handle. I'm not sure this can be done with flex without defining heights and widths, and possibly relative or absolute positioning.

Comment: thanks for the point. Agree, I already understood and had to accept the answer without using a flex. I am not sure why ios is not working well with `css grid`

Comment: Also, I think the problem is that the browser renders the image at its natural size first, which sets the height of the container, and *then* reduces the image to its defined size. But by then, the container height is fixed, leaving the gap.

Comment: Agree, that could be the case

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* added this --v */
.content {
  display: grid;  /* ----- new ------- */
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr; /* ----- new ------- */
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; /* ----- new ------- */
  column-gap: 15px; /* ----- new ------- */
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
      
      
      <!-- bring the img element above of h4 because we want it to be in the first item of our          grid layout -->
      
      
        <img src="download.png" width="50px" class="logo-image" alt="img" />
        <h4 class="headline">
          Block Title
        </h4>
        
        <p class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente
          aliquid sit, cupiditate
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="btn">
        <button>link</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

1.you need to use a two-dimensional layout which is grid (instead of flexbox) 
2.you need to use grid for the element that has .content class

```
.content { display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto 1fr; grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; column-gap: 15px; } <br>
```

3.you need to define the p element that has .text class to start from the 2nd column and ends in the 3rd column with this code: `grid-column: 2/3;`

and here is the result : https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-zhukovsky-7g12bj?file=/style.css:566-583